# Alternativa más segura para borrar un usuario

Tags: php, seguridad, parámetros

tengo este codigo :

```
<tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $usuario['id'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['nombre'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['apellidos'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['email'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['password'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['fecha_nacimiento'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['pais'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['fecha_registro'] ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php 
                                        echo "<a class='btn btn-info' href=''>Editar</a>";
                                        echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='../procedimientos/eliminarUsuario.php?id=".$usuario['id']."'>Borrar</a>";
                                         ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

Es un **fragmento de mi tabla** en la que el ultimo `<td>` tiene dos opciones, **borrar y editar**. En **borrar** le estoy pasando el **id del cliente** en la url, pero sé que eso no es seguro, ¿cómo podría hacerlo **mas** **seguro** ?

A ver, el tema es que funciona, pero ver en la url `?id=x` es malísimo, ¿cómo podría pasarlo sin que se viese el **id**?

Comment: ¿Qué código tienes en eliminarUsuario.php? Realmente la parte de seguridad la deberías llevar más ahí que en la parte del cliente que cualquiera la puede cambiar. De hecho, lo que tienes ahora es casi tan seguro como lo que se sugiere en las respuestas (que es básicamente seguridad por ofuscación/oscuridad y que es sólo tan seguro como seguro tengas el código en el servidor).

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que no se vean los parámetros en la url puedes meter tu tabla en un formulario `<form method='post' href='../procedimientos/eliminarUsuario.php'>`, cambiar el enlace por un `<button type='submit'>Borrar</button>` y el id del usuario lo podrías poner en un `<input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$usuario."'>`

Para recoger el id en tu fichero `eliminarUsuario.php` solo tienes que acceder a `$_POST['userId']`

Comment: Por ajax si quieres abreme chat y te digo como

Comment: Gracias David por responder, lo que yo estoy haciendo de pasar el id por url en las app de verdad que se hacen como tu has indicado ?

Comment: @KeTeMeTo no se abrir chats

Comment: @KeTeMeTo la idea del sitio es poner respuestas (como finalmente hiciste) que puedan servir a todos los usuarios y no sólo a una persona en el chat.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracias, iba a publicarla de todos modos pero era mas que nada por personalizarsela a su código para que fuese lo mas correcta posible

Answer (score 1):

Te expongo la respuesta por aquí, primer paso es dotar de funcionalidad al botón:

```
echo "<a class='btn btn-danger borrable'>Borrar</a>";
```

Segundo le damos un id al  del id usuario

```
 <td id=iduser><?php echo $usuario['id'] ?></td>
```

Después creamos un `javascript`, o bien lo incluimos en la misma pagina, en el cual recogemos el valor del `td` con `id=iduser` y luego lo realizamos una petición `POST` por medio de `ajax` al `php` que tu estas usando

```
../procedimientos/eliminarUsuario.php


$('.borrable').on('click',function () {
    if(confirm("Desea borrar esto?")) {
        id = $('#iduser').html()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../procedimientos/eliminarUsuario.php",
            data: {id: id},
        }).done(function(){
            alert("se borro correctamente")     
        })
});
```

Tras esto en `eliminarUsuario.php` en vez de recoger la variable por medio de `GET` tienes que recibirla por `POST`, si no sabes o no te gusta esta solución te puedo pasar otra enviando el formulario por medio de `POST`, aunque este método me gusta mas y te servirá mas para un futuro